# Refi won't boot win10 after partition resize

Tags: windows-10, boot, imac, refind

I need some suggestions about fixing the boot of a win 10 partition from rEFInd.
I had an **Imac** with a three partition boot : Linux, MacOsx and windows 10.
Respectively listed as /dev/sda2, sda4, sda5, plus /dev/sda1 boot efi partition.
I didn't need macosx anymore, and so from the linux partition with gparted, I deleted the mac partition /dev/sda4 and subsequently, move to the left & resize the Win10 partition.
The problem is that, while I can boot Linux as expected, win10 cannot start.

It fails with an error 0xc00000bb starting bootmgfw.efi.

- I can access the /boot/efi partition from linux and the efi file exists.
- My disk partition is in GPT format
- The windows partition is not corrupted and is accessible from linux
- I cannot access the mac recovery partition, command+R starts internet recovery, yeah (macosx was deleted...)
- I saved boot & win10 partitions with clonezilla before the procedure.

Any suggestion about making rEFInd booting windows again ?

Thanks a lot.
Henry

Comment: Using virtual machines is not adequate for my use case with windows, for various reasons.

Comment: Let's forget about not giving any suggestion on the topic.
I just think and won't use a Windows instance as virtual machine for video editing/recording/streaming.
Apart from that, I'm using docker instead of virtual machines for several years.

Comment: I deleted my posts. They were just for consideration. You should clarify your needs for a triple boot system. It does appear it is pooched and will need to be rebuilt.